# How to query snmp with logstash

Tags: logstash, snmp

I am trying to get SNMP data into graphite using logstash.  I initially used the snmptrap input, but I believe that this is only for traps being sent from an SNMP agent to the logstash server.  I don't see an snmp-get input.  Is there a trick like using the exec input to do this?  I basically want to graph some or all of the information that is available through SNMP over time to see trends and current information.